# Multi selection in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have list of data with `CheckBox`. I need to check or uncheck my Check Box from my `RecyclerView`. When I am trying this more than one check box is selected.

```
public class AttendanceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttendanceAdapter.MyStudentsViewHolder>{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context contexts;
    List<studinformation> data= Collections.emptyList();
    public AttendanceAdapter(Context context,List<studinformation> data){
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
        this.contexts=context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyStudentsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.customrow_students,parent,false);
        MyStudentsViewHolder holder=new MyStudentsViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyStudentsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        studinformation current=data.get(position);
        holder.studentid.setText(current.studID);
        holder.studentname.setText(current.studName);
        holder.studentid.setSelected(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return data.size();
    }
    class MyStudentsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        CheckBox studentid;
        TextView studentname;
        public MyStudentsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            studentid= (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ChkSid);
            studentname= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            studentid.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(contexts, "Item Clicked At" + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(getPosition()==0) {


               // Intent intent = new Intent(contexts, SubActivity.class);
               // contexts.startActivity(intent);
            }

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Consider accepting or commenting below the answer you got.

Answer (score 1):

`RecyclerView` will reuse the view.so when you return after scrolling it will reset the data it's happening because you are not setting your checkbox selected or not.

In your `StudInformation` model class create a property `isSelected`

```
public class StudInformation
{
  private boolean isSelected=false;

  public void setSelected(boolean param)
  {
    this.isSelected=param;
  }
  public boolean isSelected()
  {
   return this.isSelected;
   }
}
```

Inside `onClick`

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     data.get(getLayoutPosition()).setSelected(studentid.isChecked());
    }
```

In `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyStudentsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    .....
    studinformation current=data.get(position);
    holder.studentid.setSelected(current.isSelected());

}
```

[Cross reference link](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `setTag()` method to get position of each checkbox.
Use this code instead of `holder.studentid.setSelected(true);` and remove `studentid.setOnClickListener(this);`

```
holder.studentid.setChecked(data.get(position).isSelected());

holder.studentid.setTag(data.get(position));


holder.studentid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
String id = String.valueOf(cb.getTag());
Toast.makeText(
  v.getContext(),
  "Clicked on Checkbox: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```